# Converting the timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-format

I'm trying to convert the snowflake timestamp that is compatible with [Iterable date format](https://support.iterable.com/hc/en-us/articles/208183076-Field-Data-Types#date)

**My attempt:**

I have a table with the following timestamps:

```
|------------------------------|
|       table_timestamp        |
|------------------------------|
| "2021-07--19 02:45:91.000 Z" |
|------------------------------|
```

I tried using `TIMESTAMP_TZ` and I got the following resut

```
SELECT table_timestamp::TIMESTAMP_TZ 
from my_table
```

gave me output `2021-07--19 02:45:91.000 +0000`

How can I get the above timestamp in this format `2021-07--19 02:45:91 +00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast to a varchar and give, as the second parameter, the format that you want:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR('2021-07-19 02:45:31.000'::Timestamp_TZ, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

> 2021-07-19 02:45:31

(Note I changed the seconds to `31` as there isn't `91` seconds in a minute and also changed your double dash between month and day to a single. I'm assuming those were typos)

Comment: I tried to cast it to varchar but in iterable it is displaying as a string. I want it to be converted as a date data-type

Comment: If you are converting to date successfully with your `::Timestamp_TZ` then you are golden. We don't worry about the format of how snowflake (or any other DB) stores and represents the timestamp or date. Formatting is for human presentation of the data, where casting to varchar with the requested format would be the appropriate layer. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though. Also.. as far as I'm aware `STRING` and `VARCHAR` are identical in snowflake.

Comment: Instead of using VARCHAR, is it possible to just get ```2021-07-19 02:45:31``` as timestamp format?

Comment: I guess, what I'm saying, is that under the hood there is no format. It's just data stored in bits and bytes that make up a timestamp. It's not literally storing it as it shows you. The default format that it displays in your client, however, is with three decimals. Again though, it's just how it's displaying the same data under the hood. You can change the setting for your user or session utilizing the [output_timezone_format parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-timestamp-output-format) or you can cast to varchar/string and tell it what format to use.

Answer (score 1):

Give you are correct converting the date/timestamp, this is not a convertion problem, it is a presentation problem.

Thus the [Date and Time output formatting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#output-formats) help is what you need.